# How to save a dataframe into multiple files based on unique columns in spark-scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've the **inputDf** that I need to divide based on the columns **origin** and **destination** and save each unique combination into a different csv file.

(Using Spark 2.4.4)

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test").getOrCreate()

val inputRdd: RDD[(String, String, String, String, String, String)] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("City1", "City2", "Sedan", "AE1235", "80", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City2", "City3", "Hatchback", "XY5434", "100", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City3", "City1", "Sedan", "YU3456", "120", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City3", "City2", "Sedan", "BV3555", "105", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City2", "City1", "SUV", "PO1234", "75", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City1", "City3", "SUV", "TY4123", "125", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City1", "City2", "Hatchback", "VI3415", "85", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City1", "City2", "SUV", "VF1244", "84", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City3", "City1", "Sedan", "EW1248", "124", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City2", "City1", "Hatchback", "GE576", "82", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City3", "City2", "Sedan", "PK2144", "104", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City3", "City1", "Hatchback", "PJ1244", "118", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City3", "City2", "SUV", "WF0976", "98", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City1", "City2", "Sedan", "WE876", "78", "2020-02-01"),
  ("City2", "City1", "Hatchback", "AB5467", "80", "2020-02-01")
))
val inputDf = spark.createDataFrame(inputRdd).toDF("origin", "destination", "vehicleType", "uniqueId", "distanceTravelled", "date")
```

**Sample Output:**

csv file 1:

```
origin,destination,vehicleType,uniqueId,distanceTravelled,date
City1,City2,Sedan,AE1235,80,2020-02-01
City1,City2,Hatchback,VI3415,85,2020-02-01
City1,City2,SUV,VF1244,84,2020-02-01
City1,City2,Sedan,WE876,78,2020-02-01
```

csv file 2:

```
origin,destination,vehicleType,uniqueId,distanceTravelled,date
City3,City1,Sedan,YU3456,120,2020-02-01
City3,City1,Sedan,EW1248,124,2020-02-01
City3,City1,Hatchback,PJ1244,118,2020-02-01
```

csv file 3:

```
origin,destination,vehicleType,uniqueId,distanceTravelled,date
City2,City1,SUV,PO1234,75,2020-02-01
City2,City1,Hatchback,GE576,82,2020-02-01
City2,City1,Hatchback,AB5467,80,2020-02-01
```

So far I've tried getting the unique combinations into a tuple and then using a foreach on it, filtering the inputDf each time saving the filtered dataframe to csv

```
val tuple = inputDf.groupBy("origin","destination").count()
  .select("origin","destination").rdd.map(r => (r(0),r(1))).collect

tuple.foreach(row => {
  val origin = row._1
  val destination = row._2
  val dataToWrite = inputDf.filter(inputDf.col("origin").equalTo(origin) && inputDf.col("destination").equalTo(destination))
  dataToWrite.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("header", "true").save("/path/to/output/folder/" + origin + "-" + destination + ".csv")
})
```

This approach takes a lot of time as it involves filtering the inputDf every single time as the number of unique combinations are pretty huge. What would be an optimal way to do it?

**EDIT:**
Each inputDf will have data only for one date.

The output should contain files at date level.

Like:

/output/City1-City2/2020-02-01.csv

/output/City1-City2/2020-02-02.csv

/output/City1-City2/2020-02-03.csv

/output/City3-City1/2020-02-01.csv

/output/City3-City1/2020-02-02.csv

... and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `partitionBy` and divide data in separate csv file as per your combination. I have used `coalesce` to keep all data into one csv file which is not recommended if you have large data.  GO through below code which will write all  possible combination into separate csv files.

```
    scala> df.show()
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------+
|origin|destination|vehicleType|uniqueId|distanceTravelled|      date|
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------+
| City1|      City2|      Sedan|  AE1235|               80|2020-02-01|
| City2|      City3|  Hatchback|  XY5434|              100|2020-02-01|
| City3|      City1|      Sedan|  YU3456|              120|2020-02-01|
| City3|      City2|      Sedan|  BV3555|              105|2020-02-01|
| City2|      City1|        SUV|  PO1234|               75|2020-02-01|
| City1|      City3|        SUV|  TY4123|              125|2020-02-01|
| City1|      City2|  Hatchback|  VI3415|               85|2020-02-02|
| City1|      City2|        SUV|  VF1244|               84|2020-02-02|
| City3|      City1|      Sedan|  EW1248|              124|2020-02-02|
| City2|      City1|  Hatchback|   GE576|               82|2020-02-02|
| City3|      City2|      Sedan|  PK2144|              104|2020-02-02|
| City3|      City1|  Hatchback|  PJ1244|              118|2020-02-02|
| City3|      City2|        SUV|  WF0976|               98|2020-02-02|
| City1|      City2|      Sedan|   WE876|               78|2020-02-02|
| City2|      City1|  Hatchback|  AB5467|               80|2020-02-02|
+------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------+


scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("combination", concat(col("origin") ,lit("-"), col("destination")))

scala> df1.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("combination","date").format("csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save("/stackOut/")
```

> Output will be like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! Also my main need was to store files something in this manner:
stackOut/combination=City1-City2/date=2020-02-01/part-*
or stackOut/combination=City1-City2/2020-02-01.csv

Each input file has data of one date, and it needs to be segregated at origin-destination level and the output folder will contain data at origin-destination/doj level

Comment: @Flame please add date in your input, I will try and will update my answer

Comment: I've Edited the question accordingly. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Flame, please check now and let me know in case any issue